# How to add more options by trackbar?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to add more options in trackbar . like Clean image and keep text with a white background and smoothing

full code trackbar

https://controlc.com/bf3395d8

result : Code Clean image and keep text with a white background

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread("image.png")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 0, 150])
upper = np.array([78, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=5)
result = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dilate, mask)
cv2.imshow('Output', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

blur : code smoothing

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread("image.png")
blur = cv2.blur(image, (3,3))
cv2.imshow('Output', blur)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Example

[image: Text]

Comment: opencv is not a GUI toolkit. use a proper GUI toolkit. -- or use a trackbar with values 0 and 1. -- or suggest more widgets to the OpenCV developer team